# Proving this condition for convergence in a Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, approximation-theory

I have difficulty proving the following claim from a paper (a free version is [here](http://imi.cas.sc.edu/django/site_media/media/papers/1999/1999_03.pdf), see Lemma 2.4 on page 9):

> Let in a Banach space $X$ a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be given. Assume that for any $k,l$ we have 
>   $$
> ||x_k − x_l||^2 = y_k − y_l + \theta_{k,l},
> $$
>   where $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a convergent sequence of real numbers and the $\theta_{k,l}$ satisfy the property
>   $$
> \liminf\limits_{l\to \infty} \max\limits_{k<l}\theta_{k,l} = 0. \tag{1}
> $$
>   Then $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges.

I understand that the aim is to show that the $x_n$ form a Cauchy sequence which implies convergence in a Banach space.

I was able to handle the special case where all $y_j$ are zero but I don't know how to proceed when $\{y_n\}$ is a general convergent sequence.

Here is my work: If all $y_j$ are zero, $(1)$ becomes
$$
0 = \liminf\limits_{l\to \infty} \max\limits_{k<l}||x_k − x_l||^2. \tag{1'}
$$
Claim: The sequence $\{x_n\}$ is constant and therefore convergent. Assume by contradiction that there exist $n<m$ such that $x_n \ne x_m.$ Let 
$$
\epsilon=||x_n - x_m|| > 0
$$ 
Then for all $l > m$ it holds that 
\begin{align*}
\max\limits_{k<l}||x_k − x_l|| 
&\ge \max\{||x_n − x_l||, ||x_m − x_l||\} \\
&\ge \frac{1}{2}(||x_n − x_l|| + ||x_m − x_l||) \\
&\ge \frac{1}{2}||x_n − x_m|| = \epsilon/2.
\end{align*}
In particular, 
$$
\liminf\limits_{l\to \infty} \max\limits_{k<l}||x_k − x_l||^2 \ge (\epsilon/2)^2,
$$
in contradiction to $(1')$.

---

Here is the citation for the paper: *Temlyakov, V.N.*, [**Weak greedy algorithms**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1023/A:1018917218956), Adv. Comput. Math. 12, No.2-3, 213-227 (2000). [ZBL0964.65009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0964.65009).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sequence is not a Cauchy sequence, then you can pick $\varepsilon >0$ and sequences $(n_l)_{l\geq 1}, (m_l)_{l\geq 1}$ such that $n_l<m_l$ and
$$ \Vert x_{n_l} - x_{m_l} \Vert^2 \geq \varepsilon.$$
Thus, we get
$$ \varepsilon \leq \vert y_{n_l} - y_{m_l} \vert + \max_{k<m_l} \Theta_{k, m_l}.$$
If you take the limes inferior for $l\rightarrow \infty$ you obtain the contradiction $\varepsilon \leq 0$.